# how to marshal a JAXB object to org.w3c.dom.Document?

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, marshalling

This gives me a Document object with a top level node with no child nodes:

```
public static Document getDocument(Object jaxb)
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    //dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument(); 

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxb.getClass());
    context.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxb, doc);

    return doc;
}
```

This is the workaround, which seems even more inefficient, since it converts to String and then to Document.

```
public static Document getDocument(Object jaxb)
{                           
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();       
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxb.getClass());
    context.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxb, writer);

    return DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().
parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(writer.toString()));
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Turns out that the problem was not marshalling from JAXB to document. The problem was that, for some reason, namespace agnostic XPath queries do not work with the Document object returned by the first method, but work fine with the Document object returned by the second method. The solution - at least for now - is to rewrite my Xpath queries.

Comment: As a late comment: the reason why namespace agnostic XPath queries are working if you parse your marshalled data is because document builders are by default not namespace aware. When JAXB builds the DOM, the DocumentBuilder settings are not relevant because there is not parsing involved.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are doing should work.  Here is an example:

**Domain Model (Foo)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        // Create the Object
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("Hello World");

        // Create the Document
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        // Marshal the Object to a Document
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(foo, document);

        // Output the Document
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        t.transform(source, result);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><foo><bar>Hello World</bar></foo>
```

Comment: Try adding a namespace to your sample XML document and then query the Document using an Xpath expression that doesn't take into account namespaces. For example: //foo/bar versus //ns:foo/ns:bar

Comment: @JSmith - It the document is namespace aware then you should make the XPath namespace aware.  The fact that you see different behaviour when marshalling to `DOMSource` versus `Document` is evidence of this.  If you swapped parser or JAXB providers you would probably see different results.

Answer (score 15):

try this

```
    DOMResult res = new DOMResult();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
    context.createMarshaller().marshal(obj, res);
    Document doc = (Document) res.getNode();
```

Comment: Turns out that the problem was not marshalling from JAXB to document. The problem was that, for some reason, namespace agnostic XPath queries do not work with the Document object returned by the first method, but work fine with the Document object returned by the second method. The solution - at least for now - is to rewrite my Xpath queries.

Comment: Nice solution, simpler than the accepted one.